# Getting segfault when a string of length 48 or higher is given

Tags: c

I wrote a function which takes in a string and simply encodes the string (compresses if you will) the string in this format: input = aassda , output = 2a2s1d1a. My problem is if I input a string that is 47 characters or longer I get a seg fault. I attached the function bellow. I started C about a week ago so please bear with me =/

Edit: Any improvements suggestions would be nice also. I know I could make the code much more efficient but coming from a small background in python I decided to do it in the most direct way possible.

Comment: Can you also show the caller?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Right before that there's a check whether `p` points to the beginning of the string.

Comment: I don't see a problem in your function.  Please share a comolete, compilable program showing how you called the function.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Thank you, somehow missed that. Comment removed.

Comment: [No problem so far](http://ideone.com/UoTkRL).

Comment: I added the rest of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is just a junk pointer. It is never set and it is never associated with any memory. You either need to `malloc()` some memory for `string` (don't forget to `free()` it when you're done!), or you need to make it an array. That is, your two choices are:

Using `malloc()`/`free()`:

```
int main()
{
    char* string = malloc(51); // Room for 51 chars (50 letters and 1 null terminating character)

    printf("Please input a string of at most 50 chars: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    lame_function(string);

    free(string);
}
```

Using arrays:

```
int main()
{
    char string[51]; // Room for 51 chars (50 letters and 1 null terminating character)

    printf("Please input a string of at most 50 chars: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    lame_function(string);
}
```

Comment: Oh cool thanks, I thought this was the issue but I havn't read about allocation in my book as of yet =)

Answer (score 0):

**Buffer overflow is still there.**

Look at the following two code snippets.

```
char* string = malloc(51);
char string[51];
```

both of these statements are enough to allocate space for 50 characters. What about the scanf() ?

```
scanf("%s", string);
```

Will this make sure that the user will only give maximum of 50 characters? No, never. What happens if user enters more that 50 characters? . So you should use some ways to prevent overflow. For that you can use a **getc()** function in a loop. Another simple way is described below using **fgets()**.

```
fgets(str, 50, stdin);
i = strlen(str)-1;
  if( str[ i ] == '\n') 
      str[i] = '\0';
```

The fgets() will read maximum of 50 characters or when user press enter button, from stdin that is keyboard. If the last character is '\n' then make it as end of string using '\0'. Now the overflow problem is completely fixed.